# PDOException is not being reached when the sql syntax is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

when i try to send a wrong get request with an sql query like this one: `SELECT * FROM DB WHERE id=a` instead of a number, the id is a primary key with an int auto_increment value,
i get an error Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found at this line

```
$data =$con->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

instead of it reaching the catch code.

here is my code:

```
    public function read($tableName,$conditions = []) {
        $where = 'WHERE ';
        foreach($conditions as $key => $val):
            $where .= "$key=$val AND ";
        endforeach;
        $where = substr($where,0,-4);
        $con = $this->container->get('connection');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName " . (empty($conditions) ? '' : $where);
        try {
            $data = $con->query($query)
                        ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $con = null;
            return $data;
        }catch(PDOException $e) {
            $con = null;
            return ['status-code' => 500 , 'error' => $e->errorInfo()[0]];
        }
    }
```

I am expecting a catch of this error, instead of the code stopping at the query fetchAll.

Comment: Please be advised that returning array with error instead of array of data makes absolutely no sense and actually a horribly bad practice. for the better code you shouldn't catch the pdo exception, but configure a site wide exception handler instead. See https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting

Comment: Also, this function is WIDE open to SQL injections

Comment: a note: `$where` is `"WHERE"` without any condition, when `$conditions` is empty (Syntax error).